# P-value change for dropping orthogonal explanatory variable

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

Consider  a linear model $X\beta + \epsilon$, where $E(\epsilon) = 0$ and a fixed deterministic $n\times p$ design matrix $X$. $\beta = (\beta_1, ..., \beta_p)^T$,
$rank(X) = p$
Explain wheter the claim is true or not:
*If all explanatory variables are orthogonal (uncorrelated), dropping one explanatory variable will
not change the remaining p-values*

The solution in our exercise says the claim is true. Can anyone give insights why this might be true? (if it is)

Comment: The $p-value$ dont change? mmm that's weird, you can use $\mathcal{X} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1  \end{pmatrix}$ and $\textbf{Y} = (8/5,-1/6,2.1)^{T}$ Enter everything into R, and you will notice that the p value of the intercept does change, and the columns of the design matrix are orthogonal. I understood that if the columns of the design matrix are orthogonal, then the betas estimates do not change but not the p value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solutions manual is wrong. For orthogonal design, the values of $\beta_i$ will not change after dropping a variable. However, your estimate for $\sigma$, namely $\hat{\sigma}$, will, as will the number of degrees of freedom of the $t$-distributions you use to test your coefficients. This will change the $p$-values you observe, as @daniel shows in his simulation.